# Hibernate.initialize(list) vs setFetchMode

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, fetch

I'm looking for some explanation about the difference between `Hibernate.initialize(list)` and  `setFetchMode`...

As I understand they have the same purpose: Load a lazy collection.

Is there something else?

Another thing that I can imagine is that with de `setFetchMode` from the Criteria API, you can add some Criterion at your collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using FetchMode will allow you to fetch all data in a single select (by joining the root entity to other associations you are also interested in fetching).

Hibernate.initialize(list) will always issue a new select.

It's appropriate to join up to one one-to-many association while there is no strict fetch limit for the many-to-one associations.

If you need to select multiple one-to-many associations then additional selects are required. You can use:

- [Hibernate.initialize(list)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-initialization)
- [SUBSELECT fetching](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-subselect)
- [BATCH fetching](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-batch)

My advice is to use [explicit fetching policies on a per-query basis](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/) and to always validate the [actual executed SQL queries.](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-always-check-criteria-api-sql-queries/)

Comment: Also worth noting is that with Hibernate.initialize(list) it is not guaranteed that the elements inside the list will be initialized/materialized.

Comment: If it is not guaranteed that the elements will be initialized, for what can we use Hibernate.initialize(list)???